# Could a computer technically run without time measurement?

Tags: computer-architecture, computers, time

I just asked myself if a computer could **technically** run without time measurement?

With time measurement I mean the human-invented method to measure season and day/night cycles: a year has 365 days, a day has 24 hours, an hour has 60 minutes and so on. So are there any parts of the computer that rely on this measurement or would it work if we assume that we now live by just checking out where the sun is.

Comment: The vast majority of digital circuits, including your processor, your RAM and your GPU work synchronous with a clock signal, however they don't need to know exactly what day it is.

Comment: They all do, all what deals with human dates and times is just added for the humans convenience. A whole lot, maybe the majority of micros out there runs nothing that deals with human time representation, it just ticks away to whatever frequency it is running at.

Comment: See "Amulet" asynchronous ARM processor for a counterexample.

Comment: I love this SE because it makes me do stuff like research [things like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_circuit#Asynchronous_CPU). So, an answer might be an unequivocal "yes" to the question, even without really discussing what we mean by "computer". But then we have to discuss what we mean by "clock".

Comment: Not only can they _technically_ run without time measurement, but also _practically_.

Comment: most software and hardware dont care about what time it is, they would work just fine.  and the next level is hardware and software that care about relative time, again not time of day, just I need to delay N units of time, count some number of ticks of the oscillator.   then lastly you get to a small percentage of software that cares about time and date.

Comment: if your question is not about time and date, but about using clocks/oscillators, then you can do that the hardware exists, harder to manage and at the end of the day it still has points that are gated by something, it cant be all combinational or not and still do the kinds of things we are used to.

Answer (score 2):

Well that depends on what you would like to call a computer and what is a part of a computer.

If I limit myself to just the hardware, the answer is pretty much no. Only thing that needs a date is the real-time clock which is a chip for keeping time and date, but if we didn't have the need to keep track of the time of day, the implementations of RTC chips would have probably been different.

I'd go as far as to say that majority of microcontrollers used don't have any way of telling the time of the day. They use hardware that would have been considered a desktop computer in 1980s. For example, the computer in your car doesn't really need to know what time it is in order to work (other than for clock). Computers in vending machines don't need to know the time (except for log keeping purposes), computers in laundry-washing machines don't need to tell the time ass well and will work fine without any time.

On the other hand, if you consider software as a component of the system, you quite often need to know the the day at least, mostly for security purposes. For example, public key infrastructure systems work by having a key that is valid from one date to another date. After it expires, it's replaced by a new one, so you'd need time for that.

Comment: I know there would be some things that would not be possible or not possible the way it's like now but my answer is answered. Pretty much thanks!

Comment: I Think You Meant "the answer is pretty much *yes*" (to the question "Could a computer technically run without time measurement")?

Comment: and you meant "as well" and not "ass well". Because I can not see what an ass has to do in a laundry machine. ;)

Comment: @jwsc come on, don't be an as.

Comment: @jwsc Yeah, this has been an issue for a while. You can thank Toshiba for making a keyboard that randomly repeats some letters when typing. :D

Answer (score 1):

Yes they can.

Anyone old enough remembers the **Y2K** panic when radio shows were full of "experts" telling us that every microchip had calendars in them (false) that would fail at midnight 1999-12-31 and that planes would fall out of the sky, that people would be trapped in elevators / lifts, etc. In fact, most "computer" systems don't need to know the time. Most elevators, if controlled by a micro with a clock, wouldn't use the clock, etc.